# android:key attribute shows error in android

Tags: android, xml, key

i am using this code:

```
<code>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference 
android:key="music"
android:title="@string/music_title" 
android:summary="@string/music_summery" 
android:defaultValue="true"
/>;

<CheckBoxPreference 
android:key="hints"
android:title="@string/hints_title" 
android:summary="@string/hints_summery" 
android:defaultValue="true" 
/>;



</PreferenceScreen>

</code>
```

but at line  `android:key="music"` it is showing error like "Attribute is missing android namespace prefix"

how to fix this error??

Comment: Format your xml properly, remove <br> and <code> tags and put `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the very top.

Comment: @beworker done that then too.. the error isnt fixed!!

Comment: Please, update your post with your maked changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your xml with fixed mistakes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference 
android:key="music"
android:title="@string/music_title" 
android:summary="@string/music_summery" 
android:defaultValue="true"
/>
<CheckBoxPreference 
android:key="hints"
android:title="@string/hints_title" 
android:summary="@string/hints_summery" 
android:defaultValue="true" 
/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Try to paste it in your xml file and compile